# Can't connect MacBook pro to BenQ GW2765 monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, macbook

I have just got a MacBook Pro and am trying to connect it to my BenQ GW2765 monitor via this [USB-C to DisplayPort cable](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01EXKDRAC/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1). Neither the Mac nor the monitor see each other. I'd be very grateful for any help.

NB. I've tried 'Detect Displays'.

Comment: Is the macbook pro supported? (USB-C port needs to support alternative displayport mode)

Comment: @confetti Apple website says "Thunderbolt 3 digital video output: Native DisplayPort output over USB‑C"

Comment: It should be compatible then. I don't know anything about Macs but the devices and the cable seem all compatible with each other to me.